# Combine and transpose three arrays with associative keys

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

I have three arrays for instance

```
Array1
array (size=3)
0 => string 'a' (length=1)
1 => string 'b' (length=1)
2 => string 'c' (length=1)

Array2
array (size 3)
0 => string '$' (length=1)
1 => string '%' (length=1)
2 => string '^' (length=1)

Array3
array (size 3)
0 => int '1' (length=1)
1 => int '2' (length=1)
2 => int '3' (length=1)
```

I want an array4 to be have this configuration that each array's each row should be one group. For instance

```
Array4
0th 
name=a
type=$
price=1

1st
name=b
type=%
price=2

2nd
name=c
type=^
price=3
```

I tried this and gave me perfect result

```
$output = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

But when I tried this it wouldn't give expected result

```
$output = array_combine(array_combine($array, $array2),$array3);
```

Comment: one `foreach()` loop would work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### utilizing functional helpers

By using `array_map` and `array_combine`, you can skip having to handle things like counts, iterators, manual array assignment, and manual array combining.

This solution reduces complexity by using procedures which hide all that complexity behind useful, functional APIs.

```
$names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$types = ['$', '%', '^'];
$prices = [1, 2, 3];

$result = array_map(function ($name, $type, $price) {
  return array_combine(
    ['name', 'type', 'price'],
    [$name, $type, $price]
  );
}, $names, $types, $prices);

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output (some line-breaks removed for brevity)

```
[
  {"name": "a", "type": "$", "price": 1},
  {"name": "b", "type": "%", "price": 2},
  {"name": "c", "type": "^", "price": 3}
]
```

---

#### hiding your own complexity

You can even abstract away your own complexity by defining your own procedure, `array_zip_combine` — which works like `array_combine` but accepts multiple input arrays which are first "zipped" before being combined

> this solution requires **PHP 7+**

```
// PHP 7 offers rest parameter and splat operator to easily apply variadic function
function array_zip_combine (array $keys, ...$arrs) {
  return array_map(function (...$values) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
  }, ...$arrs);
}

$result = array_zip_combine(['name', 'type', 'price'], $names, $types, $prices);
```

> same solution for **PHP 5.4+**

```
// PHP 5 doesn't offer splat operator so we have to use
// call_user_func_array to apply a variadic function
function array_zip_combine (array $keys /* args */) {
  $f = function () use ($keys) { return array_combine($keys, func_get_args()); };
  return call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array_merge([$f], array_slice(func_get_args(), 1))
  );
}

$result = array_zip_combine(['name', 'type', 'price'], $names, $types, $prices);
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your `PHP 7+` solution. I think I'm missing something.  The function declaration never mentions the values. Is that ok? I would have expected `function array_zip_combine($keys, ...$values)` to be the declaration

Comment: @BeetleJuice thanks for noticing. I was using `array_slice(func_get_args(), 1)` so the code still worked, but a rest parameter is a much better fit. I first wrote the PHP 5 one and then forgot the rest parameter when converting to PHP 7 ^_^

Comment: @BeetleJuice I ended up removing `func_get_args()` from the inner function too. PHP 7 feels a bit nicer getting rid of those archaic APIs

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution. Didn't realize `array_map` could be used with multiple arrays until I read your answer. +1.

Comment: `array_combine()` can be more elegantly replaced by `compact()`

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution using `array_map` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$result = array_map(function($item) {
    return array_combine(['name', 'type', 'price'], $item);
}, array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3));

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => a
            [type] => $
            [price] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => b
            [type] => %
            [price] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => c
            [type] => ^
            [price] => 3
        )
)
```

Comment: It's a little peculiar that this answer arrives just moments after mine, seeing as tho it's virtually identical. Anyway, the nested `array_map` does double the amount of iteration as is necessary. I would recommend implementing like I did `array_zip_combine` if you're trying to make the answer more readable but still keeping iteration at a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that all three arrays are the same length and have all required data, a simple fix would be to iterate over that length and build your results array:

```
$result = []; 
$count = count($array1);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $result[$i] = [
        'name'=>$array1[$i],
        'type'=>$array2[$i],
        'price'=>$array3[$i]
    ];
}
```

`$result` holds what you need. What you're trying -- `array_combined()` -- is not made to build one array with values from the others so it won't work for this purpose. That function is to build an array whose keys come from one array and values from another.

Comment: foreach is more efficent

Comment: @Dagon You mean generally or in this case? Could you elaborate on why? Didn't know that

Comment: you run a count on every loop rather than jsut once

Comment: foreach($array1 as $ar1) this is what you are talking Dagon?

Comment: @Alex what? and why not?

Comment: @Dagon "efficiency" isn't the only metric by which we measure the quality of code. What do you mean by it, anyway? Is it *efficient* to compile? Is it *efficient* to execute? Is it *efficient* for programmers to read and understand? Is it *efficient* to debug? It's a loaded adjective, and even if one of those scenarios is true, it doesn't guarantee that the others off. Programming is full of trade-offs and varying situations will cause you to make differing choices. It would be dumb to always write code in a way that is X, Y, or Z, when the demands of the program are A-Z.

Comment: @BeetleJuice your answer is fine and communicates its intent very clearly. Since this is a significant factor in code quality, I'd say you have provided a good answer.